# Color scheme is not consistent across paging controls at SO

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs, design

SO uses color code `#F48024` as a combination color across the board even on SO Meta as well. It is consistent across logos, headers, menus, action buttons, hover effects on buttons in editor and in active tabs.

But I have found that the color scheme is NOT CONSISTENT across the paging controls on the following pages at SO:

1. Questions **(#F69C55)**
2. Developer Jobs **(#F48024)**
3. Tags **(#F69C55)**
4. Users **(#F69C55)**

The color is so dull that anyone can see it with the naked eye.

---

**Screenshot of the Developer Jobs Tab:**

[image]

---

**Screenshot of the Questions Tab:**

[image]

For consistency across the site or across the paging control, the color should be the same on active and hover states of buttons.